# ListView.SelectedItem passing to ViewModel as CommandParameter WindowsRT XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-phone, selecteditem

I have a ViewModel which defines RelayCommand , in the View i defined ListView with ListItemTemplate. I need to by clicking on a list item invoke the command with the value of the list item.

**ListView in View**

```
<ListView x:Name="listView1" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding SimilarArtists}" MinWidth="360">
                <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ResolveSearchPageViewModel.SearchCommand, Converter={StaticResource SelectionChangedConverter}, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" InputConverterParameter="{Binding ElementName=listView1}" />
                    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>


                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid MinWidth="360">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="48"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="360"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="48" Source="../Assets/singer.png"/>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Margin="10, 10, 0, 10" FontSize="25" Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView>
```

**SelectionChangedConverter**

```
public class SelectionChangedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var listView = parameter as ListView;

        return listView.SelectedItem;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**RelayCommand**

```
GoToSearchPageCommand = new RelayCommand<Artist>((item) =>
        {
            var it = item;
            _pageNavigationService.ToLoadingPage(item.Name);
        });
```

I need to pass in RelayCommand  value of SelectedItem and invoke the command. Thank you. Best regards, Dmitry

Ps. My English is not very good, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered **binding the SelectedItem property of your listview to your view-model's property**?

You don't need a command. The SelectedItem will be mapped for you as long as you declare the binding for it.

Just add a property to your view-model that reflects the type that your ItemsSource is based on and bind to it in your XAML.

```
<ListView SelectedItem = "{Binding MySelectedItem}"
```

Comment: Thank you. You mean cast SelectedItem to my domain model in the ViewModel?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by cast. Just add another property to your view-model and bind the SelectedItem from your listview to it.

Comment: Are you talking about this property? public Artist SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                _pageNavigationService.ToLoadingPage(_selectedItem.Name);
            }
        }

Comment: Your missing NotifyPropertyChanged event.